# When listing children of folder I get error 501 The request is not supported by the system

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

If I want to list files in the folder with query parameter `$orderBy` according to the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_list_children), I get a response with error `501`.

Here is a raw example of request:

```
GET /v1.0/drives/{id}/items/{id}/children?$select=name,id,folder,lastModifiedDateTime,createdDateTime,size,createdBy,lastModifiedBy,webUrl&$orderby=createdDateTime HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.microsoft.com
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

The response is:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "notSupported",
        "message": "The request is not supported by the system.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "c925ae56-8359-4e8f-98b9-92ff0c4dfc8a",
            "date": "2018-06-04T10:50:00"
        }
    }
}
```

This problem I have only with a specific OneDrive account. If I use the same API call for a different drive and folder, then it works well without any problem.

When I investigated it then it seemed like the API doesn't support parameter `$orderBy` with date variable inside for this account at all.

Does anyone know why I get this error for a specific account?

Comment: What do you get for a result if you don't request `/children`? In other words, can you add the metadata for the `DriveItem` itself to your question?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur The response to the request to URL `/v1.0/drives/{id}/items/{id}` seems to be ok. It returns JSON with the description of the folder with the fields `@odata.context`, `name`, `size`, `createdBy` etc.